# Standard Normal Variable - Inverse Mills Ratio

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

I am hoping to find whether the following holds or not:

$\dfrac{\phi(-x)}{1-\Phi(-x)}$ = $\dfrac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}$

I am working through Econometric Analysis (Greene) and manage to reach the expression on the right-hand side. However, the final solution in the book gives the one on the left-hand side.

If it does, then please state the source as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This identity follows from  the following: Since standard normal distribution is symmetric about $0$ we have $\Phi (x)=1-\Phi(-x)$. In other words $\frac {\Phi (x)} {1-\Phi(-x)}=1$.  Differentiate this  using quotient rule to derive your identity.

As observed by Math1000 in his comment below we can simply use the fact  that  $\Phi (x)= 1-\Phi(-x)=1$ together with the fact that $\phi$ is an even function to complete the proof.

Comment: Also note that $\phi(x)=\phi(-x)$ - then there is no need for differentiation :)

Comment: Thanks. Would it suffice to mention this?

Comment: Also, I'd really appreciate if you could confirm whether this holds or not:$\dfrac{\phi(-x')-\phi(-x)}{\Phi(-x')-\Phi(-x)}$ = $\dfrac{\phi(x')-\phi(x)}{\Phi(x')-\Phi(x)}$

Comment: @user508281 You are missing  a sign. RHS should have $\Phi (x)-\Phi (x')$ in the denominator.

Comment: Yes, I was making a mistake earlier. Thanks.